# Contain textfields with scroll function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

What will be the best way to contain circa 50 textfiels with a scroll function? I make a app for Iphone device only and i will contain the textfiels in the lowest third of the view. Should I use scrollview? or is there a better function. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UITableview` for that but there is a problem with this approach if the number of rows in your table exceeds the number that can fit on screen. In that case, the cells that scroll off-screen will be re-used, and the contents of the `textField` will be lost.

**Solution:**

Set the delegate for the `text fields`, and then use the `delegate` methods to grab the names as they are entered.

First, add variables to your view controller, to hold the array and the row number of the text field currently being edited.

```
var arrayOfNames : [String] = [String]()
var rowBeingEdited : Int? = nil
```

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, add:

```
cell.nameInput.text = "" // just in case cells are re-used, this clears the old value
cell.nameInput.tag = indexPath.row
cell.nameInput.delegate = self
```

Then add two new functions, to catch when the text fields begin/end editing:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
let row = textField.tag
if row >= arrayOfNames.count {
    for var addRow = arrayOfNames.count; addRow <= row; addRow++ {
        arrayOfNames.append("") // this adds blank rows in case the user skips rows
      }
  }
    arrayOfNames[row] = textField.text
    rowBeingEdited = nil
 }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    rowBeingEdited = textField.tag
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use UITableView, you may have memory issues using UIScrollview.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView with custom UITableCells containing textfields is probably what you're looking for.